# Is there any CSS method to make each letter in a word have multiple colors?

Tags: css, html

I know that is possible to have different color for every letter in a text. But how about to add random colors to every pixel of a letter o a multiple colors to a letter with CSS.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07tuz.png)

Comment: You can take a look/search for  at mix-blend-mode examples possible : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EyNgYv & http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZWMxdL  or via SVG. Beside, You should produce some codes you tried in order to get help

Answer (score -1):

The only solution that I could think of would be this:

```
<font style="color:#FF0000">H</font>
<font style="color:#FFF000">e</font>
<font style="color:#00FF00">l</font>
<font style="color:#0000FF">l</font>
<font style="color:#FF0000">o</font>
```

It would take a bit of time and effort but with copy and paste it should be quite easy. It allows you to also adjust the colors to the exact professional color you want. I do not think there is a CSS multi color feature yet.

If you would like something more complicated you can view the other ways to multi color text at:
https://rainbowcoding.com/how-to-create-rainbow-text-in-html-css-javascript/

Sorry if this answer didn't answer your question as expected but there isn't a simple way to adjust the color of every pixel.